# Matlab matrix translation and rotation multiple times

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, transform

I have a map of individual trees from a forest stored as x,y points in a matrix.  I call it fixedPositions.  It's cartesian and (0,0) is the origin.

Given a velocity and a heading, i.e. .5 m/s and 60 degrees (2 o'clock equivalent on a watch), how do I rotate the x,y points, so that the new origin is centered at (.5cos(60),.5sin(60)) and 60 degrees is now at the top of the screen?

Then if I were to give you another heading and speed, i.e. 0 degrees and 2m/s, it should calculate it from the last point, not the original fixedPositions origin.

I've wasted my day trying to figure this out.  I wish I took matrix algebra but I'm at a loss.

I tried doing cos(30) and even those wouldn't compute correctly, which after an hour I realize were in radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try the following: In your object, you already have a property `heading`. Now you add another property, `currentPosition` (an maybe rename them to `heading_robot` and `currentPos_robot`). `heading` as well as `currentPosition` should always be relative to the original coordinate system

Then you add a new method, `updatePosition` that takes `(newHeading, distance)` as input. This method will update both `heading` and `currentPosition`, by first adding the angle in `newHeading` to the angle in `heading`, after which you update `currentPosition` by adding `[distance*cos(heading),distance*sin(heading)]` (check for signs of sin/cos here!) to the old value of `currentPosition`.

Finally, to get the view of the landscape (i.e. `apparentPositions`), you run `bsxfun(@minus,fixedPositions,currentPosition)` to move the origin to where the robot is at this moment, and then you multiply with the 2D rotation matrix using the angle stored in `heading`.

Comment: currentPosition would be a matrix?  currentPosition = [x;y] to create it?

Comment: Also, because I'm using headings, not traditional angles, 0 is straight ahead, 90 degrees is to the right, and angles are measured clockwise.  To do this, I swap x and y. So the new position coordinated would be [distance*sind(heading),distance*cosd(heading)]?

Comment: @pinnacler: yes and (I think) yes. For the heading, I'd honestly have to try two or so examples to be sure that changing the heading will change the orientation in the right direction.

Comment: Senior... it worked, but I had to end up .* multiplying the rotation matrix by by [0 1 ; 1 0] in order for it to work correctly.  I'll post code in a few weeks when it's done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just first translate the coordinates `(-0.5cos(60),-0.5sin(60))` to take the origin to your target point.

Then rotate by multiplying the coordinates by a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Dimension_two).

Of course, most programming languages use radians as angle units, so that instead of 60 you must enter `60 * PI / 180`

Comment: So I translate to the point I want to be the origin, then rotate?

Also, because I want to go clockwise, with 0 degrees straight up, can I just switch x and y?  (.5sin(60),.5cos(60))?

Comment: The pair (-0.5cos(60),-0.5sin(60)) denotes the translation, not the rotation. The rotation will change from clockwise to counterclockwise if you change the sign of the angle (and hence the sign of the Sin() coefficients in the matrix).